# Can sombody, please, convert this simple SQL statment to Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
select * 
    , (
    select AVG(RatingVal)  
    from Ratings 
    where Ratings.AppID = ID
    ) as average 
from Applications
```

Comment: This is not a code supply site, although many competent people presumably could offer services for a fee.  Please try yourself and come back if you have any specific problems.

Comment: Accept more answers, you'll get more help.

Comment: as david says, this is shameful - give yourself a shake and make some effort laddie!! an 'attempt' would at least show willing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from r in Ratings
             group by r.AppID into rg
             from a in applications
             where a.ID = rg.Key
             select new {Application = a, AvgRating = rg.Avg(r=>r.RatingVal)};
```

Haven't tested it, but that should work.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me much. (If my queston hurts sombody, I applogize.)

Comment: It isn't so much that it "hurts" anybody particularly, but this site is not a place where people write your code for you for free; you get a much better response if you show that you have tried to do it yourself and it's not working. I did this one just because I like Linq, and you're lucky I got in before the Q was closed.